# Which File Manager can sort Music by Rating?

Tags: 12.04, filemanager

How can I sort files (Ex.: Music) by ratings ? Also edit ratings ? Compatible with music players and Windows OS ?

Also works under gnome 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Banshee.

There are no general file managers I know of which has ratings for files, or which cares about music as music with ratings. However, Banshee does everything you want here, except does not care about regular files. You can sort your library by rating, change the ratings, and there is a Windows port of it as well.

Comment: It works great !